# Twitter Login: Redirect is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement Login With twitter api using Twitter [oauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) PHP library. Everything seems to be work fine. I get the Twitter Sign In screen for the user. As per the code I get `$twitteroauth->http_code` as `200`. But it keep redirecting page to the same Twitter Login screen.
Here is my code:

```
function loginTwitter()
    {  
        // The TwitterOAuth instance
        $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('xxx', 'xxxxx');
        // Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to
        $request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://localhost/testsaav/socialAuth/twitterAuth');

        // Saving them into the session
        $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

        // If everything goes well..
        if($twitteroauth->http_code==200){
            // Let's generate the URL and redirect
            $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
            header('Location: '. $url);
        } else {
            // It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.
            die('Something wrong happened.');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Twitter API version has been changed 1 to 1.1. Please replace 1 to 1.1 but you need authentication class and its key for the new version.